# shouldn't we specify the topology when we talk about Borel $\sigma$-algebras?

Tags: measure-theory, convention

Maybe this is me being pedantic, but this thought has just occurred to me.

The Borel $\sigma$-algebra on X is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open sets. When we talk about Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$, we always assume open sets are the topology generated by the Euclidean norm. Why is this the case? I assume this is just convention.

are there examples when we say 'Borel $\sigma$-algebra' on a sample space rather than a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, without referring to the topology? I would assume if we take a normed space, we assume the Borel $\sigma$-algebra to be the one wrt the topology generated by the norm.

Comment: When we talk about Borel $\sigma$-algebra, a topology is always understood (at least implicitly), else it makes no sense.

Comment: @Berci indeed, i am asking are there any spaces when the topology is implicitly assumed, apart from the example i gave.